# How can I redirect a subfolder to the index file in that subfolder?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I used this code to open /subfolder/index.html when user access to /subfolder

```
[public_html/subfolder/.htaccess]
DirectoryIndex redirect.php

[public_html/subfolder/redirect.php]
header("Location: http://website.com/subfolder/index.html");
die();
```

But I think it is not optimal. Is there another way to do that? (maybe using just .htaccess file). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `DirectoryIndex index.html` will load index.html, but will not change the url in the address bar.

Otherwise, you can just use `RedirectMatch` from mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch ^/subfolder/?$ /subfolder/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

put the following code at subfolder `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  (.*)$  index.html
```

The above code will redirect any /subfolder/ request to /subfolder/index.html